# Gradle 7.0 tries to use java from old java_home despite it being set correctly everywhere

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I'm using Intellij (2021.1.1) and Gradle for my project on Win 10. The default version is 6.8, but because I'm trying to use OpenJDK 16 I tried to update to 7.0 but for some reason trying to sync or do anything with it set to 7.0 fails saying that the supplied javaHome directory is actually the one I had before and uninstalled. Tried upgrading both using the wrapper task and just changing the url as it is in the documentation. I'm also fairly certain that I'm not trying to use a 32bit version of the JDK with the 64 bit version of Intellij (plus I'd assume if I download it through Intellij itself, it'd know what to download).

In the settings I have the Gradle JVM set correctly, the Project SDK set correctly everywhere etc.. I have the correct directory in the environment variable set. I tried restarting. Running "echo $JAVA_HOME" in cmd returns the correct directory. Trying to the java.home property in gradle.properties doesn't work. I even tried to edit gradlew.bat and replaced the line where the local JAVA_HOME is set to use the correct path instead of the environment and still nothing. I tried using both an OpenJDK I downloaded manually, and one that I got through Intellij, yet still no change. I tried invalidating the caches of Intellij, also no change.

Despite that, if I set Gradle back to 6.8 that continues to work perfectly. Interestingly, if I run "java -version" in cmd it gives a different version than what JAVA_HOME is set to (it returns the JDK I've been using and haven't removed), so that's kinda weird too. At this point the only thing I can come up with is that just pressing restart wasn't long enough to properly clear it out for some reason, and I guess I'll see what happens in the morning, though I doubt that's it, honestly, since it's fine literally everywhere else

**UPDATE:** It's the morning and I checked, and the issue isn't solved, unsurprisingly. However I've found that this issue only exists with this specific project, if I make a new one (which also has Gradle 7.0 by default for some reason), it works perfectly fine there. Which means that something has gone wrong in the project, and thankfully, even if I can't find a solution here, I can probably make it work by copying the files to a new project, but I'd like to still figure out why the issue is here in the first place.

**UPDATE2:** I attempted to remove the old project and copy the files I specifically needed (so source code, build.gradle, .git folder) to a newly made project of the same name, but turns out if the project has the same name it fails again, but differently this time with `Could not open init generic class cache for initialization script` and the stacktrace IllegalArgumentException: unsupported class file major version 60. Naming the new project differently solves the problem, but I still want to fix the issue and get the old name back.

**UPDATE3:** I found what seems to have been the issue: in new projects the Gradle Home directory was reset to the default one, and when I set it back to my own, after deleting it (so Intellij would recreate it from scratch) it worked. On the other hand I remembered why I tried to use 7.0 previously and switched back to 6.8, and it's because the jar task fails with "Entry module-info.class is a duplicate but no duplicate handling strategy has been set.", even though my app is a non-modular JavaFX app. Man, all I'm trying to achieve is to create a self-contained portable .exe file at the end, so users don't need to have Java installed and don't need to run an installer for my app either

Comment: Are you using the Gradle wrapper scripts, and if not, did you install Gradle through a package manager? Some distributions have a "tweak" to Gradle so the Java version that is the default in the OS is hard-coded in it (without being able to change it with `JAVA_HOME`). No idea why they do that.

Comment: I don't think so, just whatever Intellij downloaded and uses, but looking at this did allow me to find the problem (at least kinda): I had set a custom Gradle Home directory, and in the new projects that seems to have been reset back to the default directory. So I tried deleting the custom directory then pointing to it again and it worked.  
It also reminded me why I tried using 7.0 before and switched back to 6.8: every time the jar task runs with 7.0 it fails claiming that "module-info.class" is duplicate, even though my (Javafx) application is non-modular.